# Unable to Query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

Mongodb query:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    { 
        $match : { 
           "_id" : ObjectId("60d95b5ab861ccc04fd4b598") 
        }
    },  
    { 
        $project: {
            title : "Test Product 10", 
            offers: { 
                $filter: {
                    input: "$offers", 
                    as: "offers",
                    cond: { 
                        $eq: [ "$$offers.active", true ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Golang Query:

```
productMatch := bson.D{{"$match", bson.M{"_id": objID}}}
project := bson.D{{"$project", bson.D{{"offers", bson.D{{"$filter", bson.D{{
        "input", "$offers"}, {"as", "offers"}, {"cond", bson.D{{
        "$eq", bson.D{{"$$offers.active", true}}}}}}}}}}}}
pipeLine := mongo.Pipeline{productMatch, project}
result, err := s.DB.Collection(collectionProducts).Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeLine)
```

Comment: Can you please add the full error message.

Comment: Youi don't need `cond: { $eq: [ "$$offers.active", true ] }`. Using just `cond: "$$offers.active"` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Jens ERROR   product/service.go:63   Error getting product     {"error": "(InvalidPipelineOperator) Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$$offers.active'", "id": "60d18c90dcb548b79b898da8"}

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
cond: { 
    $eq: [ "$$offers.active", true ]
}
```

The value for `$eq` is an *array*. [`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) is to model *documents*. To model an array, use [`bson.A`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#A).

So instead of:

```
{"cond", bson.D{{
    "$eq", bson.D{{"$$offers.active", true}}}}}
```

Use

```
{"cond", bson.D{{
    "$eq", bson.A{"$$offers.active", true}}}}
```

Comment: error message:

```product/service.go:63   Error getting product     {"error": "EOF", "id": "60d18c90dcb548b79b898da8"}```

Comment: @NithinUrs Please update your question and describe the code that you used to test icza's proposed answer. Also add the error that you got.

Comment: @NithinUrs I tried the solution I posted and it worked for me. If it doesn't work for you, please provide a [mcve].